# Unity Networking | Authority issue - players can move but not shoot independently

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I am making a multiplayer game using Unet. Currently, the players can move independently (i.e., if user one presses d, then character one will move right if user two presses d then character two will move right) - however, both players shoot 'through' the host.

My movement code is inside the PlayerUnit script. It has one `!isLocalPlayer` check at the top, in the `Update()` method. This check is performed before the script detects for user inputs (i.e., w, s, mouse1, etc.).

This all works fine when the correct key is pressed; the proper action is performed. 
Eg:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(up))
    Jump();
```

Shooting works in a slightly different way as it involves a different script.

When mouse1 is pressed, the `Shoot()` method in PlayerUnit is called. This, in turn, uses a `Command` inside the PlayerUnit script to call a `ClientRpc` in a separate WeaponMaster script, which calls the Fire() coroutine.

In PlayerUnit:

```
private void Shoot ()
{   
    //WeaponMaster.wM.Shoot();
    CmdShoot();

}

[Command]
void CmdShoot ()
{
    WeaponMaster.wM.RpcShoot();
}
```

In WeaponMaster:

```
[ClientRpc]
public void RpcShoot ()
{
    if (ammo != 0)
    {
        if (isAutomatic == true)
        {
            keepFiring = true;
            StartCoroutine(Fire());
        }

        if (isAutomatic == false && noQuickFire == true)
           StartCoroutine(Fire());
    }
}
```

WeaponMaster has one `!isLocalPlayer` check as well, once again in the `Update()` method.

When debugging, I know that `playerTwo`'s (client) `Shoot()` method is being called, but `playerOne`'s RpcShoot is being executed. Everything works fine when `playerOne` shoots - hence the problem of both players shooting 'through' the host.

All the scripts are on the same object with one `NetworkIdentity` component.

I'm convinced the problem is just a missing authority check - but I've tried adding `!isLocalPlayer` tests in the various methods to no avail.

Comment: Could you add more code for context? Like what you describe where and how exactly you used `isLocalPlayer` etc. Also what is `Fire` doing exactly?

Comment: `WeaponMaster.wM.RpcShoot();` also pretty much looks like a Singleton pattern so my guess would be you simply assign the wrong reference to the `wM` field?

Comment: Or in other words since you go through the server .. wouldn't always the same object shoot no matter what since on the server it is always the same reference in `wM`..?

Comment: @derHugo What you said about the singleton makes sense. So, I just have to call `RpcShoot` in a different way - i.e. with a `GetComponent<>`? I'll add more context when I get home, I'm away from my PC right now.

Comment: yeah definitely use `GetComponent` or directly `[SerializeField] private WeaponMaster weaponMaster;` within the `PlayerUnit` and reference the according **own** `WeaponMaster` component there. Then I would in general leave each `ClientRPC` in the class that also calls it just so it is better find- and maintainable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said my guess is that a Singleton pattern in `WeaponMaster.wM` is not a good approach here since you get the wrong reference and since everything goes through the server might simply always get the same reference no matter who called `CmdShoot`.

---

You should rather store each players **own** `WeaponMaster` reference and go through it like in `PlayerUnit`

```
// Already reference this via the inspector (drag&drop)
[SerializeField] private WeaponMaster weaponMaster;

// or as fallback get it on runtime
private void Awake()
{
    if(!weaponMaster) weaponMaster = GetComponent<WeaponMaster>();
}

public void Shoot ()
{  
    if(!isLocalPlayer) return;

    CmdShoot();
}

[Command]
private void CmdShoot ()
{
    RpcShoot();
}

// Personally in general I would leave any RPC
// as close to the method calling it
// as possible for better maintainability
[ClientRpc]
private void RpcShoot ()
{
    weaponMaster.Shoot();
}
```

and accordingly in `WeaponMaster`

```
public void Shoot()
{
    if (ammo == 0) return;

    if (isAutomatic)
    {
        keepFiring = true;
        StartCoroutine(Fire());
    }
    else if (!isAutomatic && noQuickFire)
        StartCoroutine(Fire());
}
```

Comment: Awesome - I didn't even realize I was using a singleton, so I did some reading and now understand everything going wrong a lot more. Thanks man, have a good one.